# Add xml child elements to specific parent node in C# with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml that goes like this:

```
<Equipment>
     <ModificationDate>
             <Data>
             </Data> 
     </ModificationDate>
</Equipment>
```

I need to add this sequence to the Data node:

```
<Table>
       <Name />
       <Value />
       <Number />
</Table>
```

The problem is that I need to add many Table nodes in the Data node. If iot was only one I would have finished it by now.

Whenever I try to add 1 table node with its elements, I do the first one correctly, but when I try to do the same to newer nodes i create the Table nodes but its elements all go to the first Table node, leaving the others empty.

That's why I wanted to know if anyone here knows how to add the new Table node and add the elements by using the Tabel index.

Or any other way, all I need to do is to **add the elements to the specific Table node that I want**, keeping in mind that they're all the same structure and keep the same name.

I've searched high and low and haven't come up with an answer

**EDIT:**

I'll try to explain better. I have the first xml and I need to add the second structure to the Data field. The problem is that the second structure will be repeated about 500 times inside Data.

I can add those 500 Table ... but when I try to add each number/value/name to its corresponding Table it doesn't work. I can only add number/value/name to the first Table created. That's why, in some way I need to access each Table separately and add the elements to it, so it will keep that structure. the final xml should look something like this:

```
<Equipment>
     <ModificationDate>
             <Data>
                  <Table>
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                  </Table>
                  <Table>
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                  </Table>
                  <Table>
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                  </Table>
             </Data> 
     </ModificationDate>
</Equipment>
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
<Equipment>
     <ModificationDate>
             <Data>
                  <Table>
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                       <Name />
                       <Value />
                       <Number />
                  </Table>
                  <Table />
                  <Table />
             </Data> 
     </ModificationDate>
</Equipment>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *entirely* clear what you need, but you can always use this to get to a table element by index:

```
var table = doc.Root                         // Equipment
               .Element("ModificationData")  // ModificationData
               .Element("Data")              // Data
               .Elements("Table")
               .ElementAt(index);

// Now add to that element
```

On the other hand, if you're adding a new table node for each name/value/number, I don't see why you would need to access them by index...

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow morning. I just left my work and the code is there. Yes I need top add a new table for each number/name/value. The probem is when I try to add that new value/number/name it just goes to the first Table i created. The others remain empty

Comment: @morcillo: Well it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong without seeing the code, really. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions about how to write questions which are easier to answer.